# Matlab s-function with legacy code for char* argv[]

Tags: c++, matlab, mex, s-function

I want to integrate a C++ function with the Matlab Legacy Code Tool.

The C++ function call looks like: `void init(int argc, char* argv[], struct sStruct *pStruct)`

What would be the corrosponding legacy code tool function specification. So far I have something like: `void init(int16 p1, int8 p2[], sStruct work1[1])`

but of course compiler cannot convert **'int8_T* {aka signed char*}' to 'char**'**

Comment: Have you tried `int8 p2[][]` ? I agree that Matlab's documentation about this is quite crappy.

Comment: ya, but I think there is no such thing [][] in legacy code tool...still the same error

Comment: According to documentation some stuff like this exists but I don't understand in what context : https://fr.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/integrating-existing-c-functions-into-simulink-models-with-the-legacy-code-tool.html
Else, `void**` seems to be possible, so maybe you can modify your C code passing `void**` instead of `char* []` and use `reinterpret_cast<>()` inside. There seem not to be an easy/non-intrusive solution to your problem unfortunately.